# Список всех таблиц в 1 запросе через разделитель

Tags: sql, sql-server

Использую Microsoft SQL Server 2012. Как выделить все таблицы у конкретной базы в 1 строчку через разделитель.

Допустим существует база данных TestDB с таблицами panel, settings, temp, log
Нужно провести запрос ответ которого будет
"panel|settings|temp|log"
По сути эта информация -

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM TestDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables
```

Только вот как этот запрос преобразовать в 1 строку через разделитель

Как я понял функция group_concat для данной задачи не походит.

Comment: На счет group_concat вы не правы. Ее, конечно, нет в MS SQL, зато запрос гуглу "MS SQL group_concat" выдает кучу ссылок по любой из которой есть примеры того что вам надо

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста хоть 1 рабочий пример, я гуглил перед тем как задать здесь вопрос, и ничего путного увы не нашел.

Comment: Берем первую же ссылку гугла: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415  от туда берем второй ответ, в котором заменяем `column_name` на `table_name`, запятую на вертикальную черту, имя таблицы на INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables. Проверяем - работает. итого: `SELECT STUFF(
             (SELECT '|' + table_name
              FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables
              FOR XML PATH (''))
             , 1, 1, '')
`

Comment: Вот что получается TABLE_NAME>|</TABLE_NAME><TABLE_NAME>|</TABLE_NAME><TABLE_NAME>|</TABLE_NAME><TABLE_NAME>|</TABLE_NAME><TABLE_NAME>|</TABLE_NAME><TABLE_NAME>|</TABLE_NAME><TABLE_NAME>|</TABLE_NAME><TABLE_NAME>|</TABLE_NAME><TABLE_NAME>|</TABLE_NAME><TABLE_NAME>|</TABLE_NAME><TABLE_NAME>|</TABLE_NAME><TABLE_NAME>|</TABLE_NAME>

Comment: Тогда не представляю чем вам помочь. Я проверил это у себя - выдало имена таблиц разделенные вертикальной чертой

Comment: Такой результат как у вас удалось получить заменив знак `+` после вертикальной черты в кавычках на пробел. Т.е. вы неправильно скопировали код, потеряли знак плюс

Comment: @Mike Можете, пожалуйста, оформить ваш комментарий как ответ?

Answer (score 1):

Объединение записей в строку в sql-server делается через объединение результата в XML. При этом, когда у колонки нет простого названия (а у колонок собираемых формулами, например с использованием оператора плюс, названия нет) то ms-sql не добавляет в эту XML теги и в итоге получаем чистую строку. Остается удалить из строки начальный символ `|` с помощью `STUFF()`.

```
SELECT STUFF(
             (SELECT '|' + table_name
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables
                 FOR XML PATH ('')
             ), 1, 1, ''
            )
```