# Каждые три строки в одну sql server

Tags: sql-server

Есть таблица следующего вида:

```
one                                                                coupon_id   id
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
31460000183244620758531929                                              NULL    1
7,  ,22, ,42, ,61,70, ,9, ,26, , , ,64,73,81, , ,29, ,45, ,69,76,88     NULL    2
3,18,20, ,41,50, , , , 7, , , ,47,51, ,72,86, 9, ,28, ,49,52, ,74,      NULL    3
31460000180621488768314821                                              NULL    4
 ,  ,22,33,48,51,  ,72, , 5, ,28,36, ,52, ,75, , , ,29,38, ,54,64,79,   NULL    5
3, ,22, ,40, ,66, ,80, 4, ,23,34, , , ,74,81, 6,13,26,38,44, , , ,      NULL    6
```

Первая строка 26 -ти значный номер билета, две последующие строки это игровые комбинации.

Мне нужно каждые три строки помещать в одну и так далее до конца таблицы.

Промежуточный вид: нужно каким образом пронумеровать строки, но не каждую отдельно, а так чтобы первые три строки имели один идентификатор ну скажем 1, а следующие три строки уже 2 и так далее.

```
one                                                                coupon_id   id
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
31460000183244620758531929                                              1   1
7,  ,22, ,42, ,61,70, ,9, ,26, , , ,64,73,81, , ,29, ,45, ,69,76,88     1   2
3,18,20, ,41,50, , , , 7, , , ,47,51, ,72,86, 9, ,28, ,49,52, ,74,      1   3
31460000180621488768314821                                              2   4
 ,  ,22,33,48,51,  ,72, , 5, ,28,36, ,52, ,75, , , ,29,38, ,54,64,79,   2   5
3, ,22, ,40, ,66, ,80, 4, ,23,34, , , ,74,81, 6,13,26,38,44, , , ,      2   6
```

нужно чтобы было так: (игровые комбинации сократил для удобства отображения)

```
ticket_num                  comb1                                      comb2
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
31460000183244620758531929  7, ,22, ,42, ,61,70, ,9, ,26, , , ,64,...  3,18,20, ,41,50, , , , 7,...
```

Я попробовал сделать это:

```
Declare @ones AS Nvarchar(MAX) -- It must not be MAX if you have few numbers     
SELECT @ones = COALESCE(@ones + ',', '') + one    
FROM   TB_tickets where one IS NOT NULL    
SELECT @ones
```

но  у меня вся таблица теперь в одной строке.

Может есть еще какие то варианты.

Comment: А в каком порядке их нумеровать ? пока не задана явная сортировка SQL не гарантирует порядка строк. так что он вполне может выдать подряд 3 строки с 26-значным номером. т.е. сейчас вашей таблицей фактически пользоваться нельзя. потому как нельзя сказать какие комбинации к какому номеру билета относятся

Comment: *Есть таблица следующего вида* В каком ТОЧНО виде (полное описание структуры)? *чтобы первые три строки* А как определить, какие "первые три"? какую именно сортировку для этого нужно применить?

Comment: А так-то задача тривиальная: `.. STRING_AGG(field) .. (ORDER BY ?) .. GROUP BY (ROW_NUMBER() - 1) / 3 ..`. Ну или если версия не позволит, то же, но через FOR XML.

Comment: @Mike я добавил столбец ID int identity(1,1) для порядка строк

Comment: Ну так откорректируйте вопрос в соответствии с новыми реалиями... плюс добавьте требуемый результат на показанных исходных. Ещё лучше - сделайте [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk).

Comment: @Akina one (nvarchar(100),NULL)            id (PK, int, Не NULL)      coupon_id (int,Не NULL)

Comment: Вы видите разницу между "откорректируйте вопрос" и "добавьте в комментарий"???

Comment: пардон, сейчас все будет

Comment: `select one, (row_number() over(order by id)) / 3 NUM from ...` даст одинаковые номера у каждой тройки строк, далее обернуть это во внешний запрос, сгруппировать по номеру NUM и как и предлагал выше Akina сделать string_agg (при его наличии) или for xml (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612118/194569) собрать целую строку в пределах группы

Comment: @Mike Спасибо, получилось! А можно подробнее продолжение?

Comment: а что вы кстати имеете ввиду под 'в одну строку', читая это все вам предлагают решения что бы собрать это действительно в одну строку, в одну единственную колонку. Но что то мне сейчас подсказало, что все таки вы хотите 3 отдельные столбца в строке, иначе работать дальше с этим будет нереально

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/624344/194569

Comment: @Mike да, я пожалуй не совсем верно выразился. По сути нужно в одну строку, в три колонки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select max(case when num=1 then one end) ticket_num,
       max(case when num=2 then one end) comb1,
       max(case when num=3 then one end) comb2
  from (
    select one, grp, row_number() over(partition by grp order by id)  num
      from (
        select one, id, (row_number() over(order by id)-1)/3 grp
          from test
      ) x
  ) y
  group by grp
```

[Тест на sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9b34c/3)

Внутренний row_number()/3 создает номера групп, для последующей сборки их в одну строку. Внешний row_number нумерует строки внутри группы 1,2,3 определяя тем самым колонку, в которую надо поместить данную строку.

Comment: Спасибище! огромное! то что надо!